# Testing React API - Unexpected Token error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, pact

I have a basic `React` app created using `create-react-app`. I am trying to get started with [Pact](https://docs.pact.io/) to do contract testing on my API using the [Javascript implementation guide](https://docs.pact.io/implementation_guides/javascript).

I have followed the steps in the above link exactly and have created a basic test which essentially does nothing just so I can get the test to run:

```
import { Pact } from '@pact-foundation/pact';

it('works', () => {
  expect(1).toEqual(1);
});
```

When running `npm run pactTest` I get the following error:

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token

This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

Here's what you can do:
 • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
 • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
 • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

Details:

/path/to/file.test.pact.js:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import { Pact } from '@pact-foundation/pact';
                                                                                                ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/script_transformer.js:403:17)
```

If I change the import line to: `const Pact = require('@pact-foundation/pact');` then it works.

The problem is that I can't use `require` instead of `import` for anything more than this dummy example, because I use `import` all over the `React` project.

There must be something else that im missing, since the [Javascript implementation guide](https://docs.pact.io/implementation_guides/javascript) uses `import { Pact } from '@pact-foundation/pact';`

Comment: Thanks @darkpool (and sorry), the example is using ES6 syntax by default (which requires transpiling using tools like Babel). I've updated the docs to help with others in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below config right after transform object in jest.config.js

```
  '^.+\\.js$': 'babel-jest
```

Below is the example for your ref

```
  module.exports = {
     moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'json', 'vue'],
     transform: {
         '.+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$':
         'jest-transform-stub',
         '^.+\\.(js|jsx)?$': 'babel-jest'
     },
     moduleNameMapper: {
         '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1'
     },
     snapshotSerializers: ['jest-serializer-vue'],
        testMatch: [
            '<rootDir>/(tests/unit/**/*.spec.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)|**/__tests__/*.(js|jsx|ts|tsx))'
     ],
     transformIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/']
  };
```

Comment: Unfortunately im still getting the same error. Is there something more I could try?

Comment: Okey can you try this node node_modules/.bin/jest --clearCache

Comment: Thanks, got it working. I also had to create a `.babelrc` file containing `{"presets": ["env", "react"]}`

Comment: Hoo you didn’t do that before. Good catch. Keep learning and keep coding :)